# What is the right XPath expression?

Tags: html, xpath

Given the following HTML from a Wiki page:

```
<li>
  <a href="/wiki/Aluminium_bromide" title="Aluminium bromide">Aluminium bromide</a> – AlBr
  <sub>3</sub>
</li>
```

what should the XPath expression be, to be able to return:

> AlBr3

I have tried:

```
string(//li[/a = "Aluminium bromide"]//-)
```

But it just returns an error.

Comment: If you know that the HTML page is exactly like this then the simplest expression that returns "AlBr3" is "AlBr3". But presumably you want to find the answer even if the page is a bit different from that shown. But how different? If it can vary, we need to know which bits are fixed and which are variable. For example, will the content of the `<a>` element always be the same as the `@title` attribute?

Comment: And please, never tell us that something "returns an error" without telling us what that error is.

Comment: The page in question is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inorganic_compounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit tricky because the way the nodes are nested.

But you could say "all text nodes inside the `<li>` that contains an `<a>` with a value of 'Aluminium bromide', except the text node of that `<a>` itself".

```
//li[a = 'Aluminium bromide']//text()[not(parent::a)]
```

and then do some post-processing (join, trim, etc).

Comment: @StefanHegny I don't think so, you would miss the `3` AFAICT.

Comment: Oh sure, I missed that one. Sorry!